# Is there any sample code that allows user the google credentials in their application using OAuth in iphone sdk

Tags: objective-c

Can any one provide a sample code so that I can login to my application with the google credentials using OAuth.

Answer (score 1):

Google has [GData.framework](http://code.google.com/p/gdata-objectivec-client/) which allows access to google services. Try checking it out. Not sure about access to 3rd party apps with google credentials.

Comment: Yeah I downloaded that GData.framework and I am confused of using it in my application.Any suggestions??

Comment: There should be a tutorial in wiki of project site. Other than that -not sure. Haven't used it extensively.

Comment: Hmm K i will try that.Anyway Thanks for ur suggestions.